# Size of URLImage as a Label icon

Tags: image, codenameone, scaling

My goal is to download an image of any size, apply a circular mask to it, and show the image on the screen with a size of 512 x 512.

I try to use a `URLImage` with a 512 x 512 placeholder and circular mask and put it on a `Label` via `setIcon()`. However the label gets the correct height (512) while the image is drawn in its natural size, in a circular shape. I want it to fill the label vertically, preserving the aspect ratio.

My code:

```
           EncodedImage img = URLImage.createToStorage(
                roundPlaceholder, // roundPlaceholder is 512 x 512  
                "rounded" + uid, 
                imageUrl, 
                URLImage.createMaskAdapter(mask)); // mask is 512 x 512 

           myLabel.setIcon(img);
```

Am I missing something, or isn't this the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: download the image in its natural size, but keep the placeholder size as you want. Determine if the width or height is longer, and use the .scaledWidth or .scaledHeight methods of the image class to resize it and preserve the aspect ratio. You may have a little more work to do to make sure your mask size matches the image before you apply it.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion didn't work. Looks like the URLImage gets drawn at a tiny size no matter what width/height I try to give it.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the mask adapter is "scale to fill" not the natural size. So this might be misleading to you. You might be expecting a "scale to fit" approach but that might be problematic as it might produce blank spots.

See: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.java#L175-L183

Comment: Ok, the mask is a red herring. If i just use a blank 512 x 512 image as a placeholder, the result is the same. If I on the other hand adds the same image to the project's resources and call setIcon() with that, it gets drawn in the correct size. Maybe there is a way to convert the URLImage to a normal image?

Comment: No. URLImage by definition resizes the download image to fit/fill the size you give it. The logic/use case is to fit a specific space designated for said image... This is important both for application design and so the replace won't reflow/disrupt and will be seamless. It sounds like you don't want URLImage & should really use just a simple file download which will probably serve your needs better.

Comment: Ok Shai, I figured it out. Turns out I had previously downloaded a smaller version of the same image in a different part of the app, using the same name. Apparently the small version got reused, even after I cleared the simulator storage. Thank you anyway.